# Отправить Json на сервер через Fetch и получить тот де json уже на клиенте, используя данные вставить в DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const $formBike = $('#addBike');

        $formBike.on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            const valueBike = $formBike
                .serializeArray()
                .reduce(function (result, input) {
                    result[input.name] = input.value;
                    return result;
                }, {});

            let root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

            fetch(root +  '/posts', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(valueBike)
            })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                addElementsIntoDom(data);
                console.log(data);
            });
        })
    });

function newBike(bike) {

    return $("<div class='col-4'><div class='bike-box' data-id=' + bike.id + '><div class='bike-box-img'>" +
        "<img src='" + bike.image + "' alt='bike'></div><div class='bike-box-title'><h6>" + bike.title + "</h6>" +
        "</div>" + (bike.checked ? '<div class="bike-box-checked"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
            '</div>' : '') + "<div class='bike-box-description'><p>" + bike.description + "</p><div class='bike-box-price'>" +
        "<p>" + bike.price + "</p></div></div>" + "</div></div>");
}

const wrapper = $('.card-block');

function addElementsIntoDom(data) {

    data.forEach(function (data, bike) {
        wrapper.append(newBike(bike))
    })
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что я делаю что то неправильно, выдает ошибку на data.forEach, не могу понять что именно делаю неправильно

Comment: Поднимите на одну строку выше `console.log(data);`, и что он выводит?

Comment: Выводит объект с данными, которые были в json

Comment: У вас там не массив, а объект `{name: value}` У объектов нет метода `forEach`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Есть еще вопрос: я могу с локального веб сервера обратится к open api и получить адекватный ответ? 
Еще, вы не знаете open api, в который можно записывать json и хранить некоторое время?

Comment: Заголовок у Вас через-чур информативный, да еще и с ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

Объект `key-value` можно итерировать по ключам:

```
function addElementsIntoDom(data) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
        var bike = data[key];
        wrapper.append(newBike(bike))
    })
}
```

Comment: Появились новые ошибки. Вы не знаете, можно ли с локального сервера отправлять запрос к open api? Вы не знаете online open api ? Хочу отправить json и хранить его там некоторое время. Пробовал  app.apiary.io, но он только с GET запросами работает, или я что то не разобрал

Comment: Нет, я не пользуюсь внешними сервисами для таких простых вещей. Поднимите себе `redis` какой-нить.

Comment: В принципе, можно мокнуть бекенд на клиенте... [Первое, что попалось](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax)